# A Classic Blunder

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

My boss arranged for me to run things whilst he was off on a European vacation. While almost everything was set up for a graceful transfer of power, he must have been busy and distracted, because he forgot to give me the password to the server room!  One hopes I wouldn't have to use it, but these details are important.

It's a simple enough lock--just a numeric keypad, but I don't even know the length of the password. I looked around my boss's desk for something that might be a clue (that's how these things work, right?) and only found a post-it note with what seems like the start of a nerdy crossword puzzle on them...

> (1) Area ministered over by Morrison
> (3) What ghosts, vampires, and fey aren't
> (5) "Stand up and be ________!"
> (7) A Fighter or Barbarian's most important stat
> (8) With "The," Cliff Johnson gave him an Errand
> (9) EA's marketplace

I already tried the numbers in order--nothing.  If those are the numbers, there's some order to them I don't know. So...

***What's the password?***

Hint:

> I managed to find my boss's vacation plans, and he was headed to the exotic European country of Florin.  Does that help?

Comment: This sounds like the beginning of a creepypasta story.

Comment: Isn't Florin from _The Princess Bride_? And isn't it fictional? Hmmm...

Comment: You fools! You fell victim to.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) Area ministered over by Morrison

> Australia

(3) What ghosts, vampires, and fey aren't

> Mortal (Thanks to @MrSethward!)

(5) "Stand up and be ________!"

> Counted (thanks to @Stiv!)

(7) A Fighter or Barbarian's most important stat

> Strength

(8) With "The," Cliff Johnson gave him an Errand

> Fool

(9) EA's marketplace

> Origin

What we can do is

> put them into the order in which they appear in [Vizzini’s iocane speech](https://princessbride.fandom.com/wiki/Vizzini) from the movie *The Princess Bride*, namely: FOOL, COUNTED, AUSTRALIA, ORIGIN, STRENGTH, MORTAL. Thanks to @JeremyDover for this insight!

Then,

> Taking the associated numbers with the order above, we get the password 851973.

*OP's Afterword:*

> And 8/5/1973 was the release date for the original Princess Bride novel!
>
>
>
>
>
> Well, okay, it wasn't, I couldn't find the exact date of release, but William Goldman would say to never let reality get in the way of a good story!

Comment: I think a more common word for (5) would be rot13(PBHAGRQ) but I am equally at a loss right now as to how to use these answers...

Comment: Got to same place as you, and equally lost. For (3), wasn't sure about the current answer, could be rot13(ZBEGNY) instead?

Comment: rot13(vs lbh punatr nyvir gb zbegny, nyy fvk bs gurfr jbeqf nccrne va Ivmmvav'f fcrrpu qhevat uvf vbpnar pbzcrgvgvba jvgu Jrfyrl, va gur beqre SBBY, PBHAGRQ, NHFGENYVN, BEVTVA, FGERATGU, ZBEGNY)

Comment: Thanks to you all — and fantastic find especially, @JeremyDover !